# How to control a storyboard animation from C# and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There's a lot of questions around this on the net, but after reading them, and the MS docs on animation control, I'm unable to mimic storyboard control from XAML event triggers in C# code.

In this XAML file, I have a canvas that I am rotating. I'd like to add interactivity to the rotation,

```
<Window x:Class="GraphicsBook.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:k="clr-namespace:GraphicsBook;assembly=Testbed2D"
    Title="2D Testbed"
    KeyDown="KeyDownHandler"
   Height="600"
   Width="600" >
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

        <StackPanel x:Name="stack" DockPanel.Dock ="Top" Orientation="Vertical" Background="#ECE9D8">
            <Button Name="StartAnimationClick">Start animation</Button>
            <Button Name="StopAnimationClick" Click="stopAnimationClick">Stop animation</Button>
            <Canvas x:Name="Grid">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="CanvasRotation" CenterX="300" CenterY="300" Angle="0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            </Canvas>

            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="StartAnimationClick">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="GridRotationStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="CanvasRotation"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                From="0.0" To="360.0"
                                Duration="00:00:10.00" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <!--<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="StopAnimationClick">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="GridRotationStoryboard"/>
                </EventTrigger>-->
            </StackPanel.Triggers>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The commented event trigger,

```
<!--<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="StopAnimationClick">
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="GridRotationStoryboard"/>
                    </EventTrigger>-->
```

Does indeed work as expected, that is, if I click the button, the animation stops. However, the version of the XAML above tries to replicate this functionality in C#, but this doesn't work. The click handler looks like this,

```
    private void stopAnimationClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("Stop animation");
        // ???
    }
```

I'm unable to control the animation object in `???`, not matter what technique I try to get a handle on it. I must be plumbing the pieces incorrectly somehow, but I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8  Read the explanation at the top. You could try GridRotationStoryboard.Stop(this) but it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic what the `EventTrigger` does by calling `BeginAnimation` with a second argument of `null`:

```
private void stopAnimationClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CanvasRotation.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, null);
}
```